# laravel fetch dropdown query data value from model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form and there is a dropdown for this. In a view page i want to fetch the data from the model.

model function

```
 public static function allVenueClientList() {

        /* Also if possible i want to add ($users = DB::table('clients') join query on this query which is already working for me.

        return Client::where('type', static::CLIENT_TYPES['Venue'])
        ->orWhere('type', static::CLIENT_TYPES['Both'])
        ->pluck('name', 'id')->all();

        */

        $users = DB::table('clients')
        ->join('users', 'clients.id', '=', 'users.user_id')
        ->where('users.status', '=', 'Active')
        ->where('users.id', '!=', '1')
        ->select('clients.name', 'clients.id')
        ->get();
        return $users;
}
```

My view page code:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('client_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
{{Form::label('client_id', trans('admin.venue.fields.client_id'),['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label'])}}
<div class="col-md-6">
    {{Form::select('client_id',[0 => trans('admin.venue.select.client_id')] + \App\Client::allVenueClientList(), old('client_id', isset($venue) ? $venue->client->id : 0), ['class' => 'form-control select'])}}
    @if ($errors->has('client_id'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('client_id') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

How can i get $users data on this dropdown also if it is possible to the first query change as per second query ?

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand,

Comment: just passing the query from the dropdown to get dropdown value...when commented query work for me but on addition of join query when i return $users it throw error

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller function which defines the above mentioned function of model pass the data by using compact data...

```
        like this $compactdata= your query result.
       return view('your view', compact('compactdata'))
```

and then loop through result in view if it is collection other wise just show result in view withoutloop as you did it above.
Please checkout the syntax error.I am not sure about syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I will admit not entirely understanding the question, but my response is too large for a comment.

It sound like you are going to want to offload some of this into scripts.

script:

```
function usersearch(client_id)
{
        $.post('usersearch', {
             _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
             client_id: client_id,
         }
        )
        .done(function(data) {
                document.getElementById('myotherdropdown').innerHTML = data;
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "I did an oops" );
        });
}
```

Then the current select gets an event

```
<select name="client_id" onchange=usersearch(this.value)>
```

in web.php

```
Route::post('/usersearch', 'JavaController@usersearch');
```

in JavaController

```
public function usersearch()
{
    $sku = Request::get('client_id');
    $options = '';

    $result = whatever you need to do here;

    foreach($result as $row) {
        $options .= "<option value=\"".$row->user_id."\">".$row->user_name."</option>";
   }

    return $options;
}
```

Obviously given your setup, things won't be exactly as here, but the idea itself seems to be what you are going for.

If you really want, you can even throw the token around in the script as well for a little extra security.

```
$.post('usersearch', {
 _token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
 client_id: client_id,
}
```

Hopefully this is what you were asking for.